# error converting varchar to numeric : SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008, delphi-2010

I have this SQL statement but it return :  "error converting varchar to numeric"

```
ADOTailles.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO tailles (numOF, taille, quantite, prixVente) VALUES(''' + numOF.Text + ''',''' + C.Caption + ''',''' + Q.Text + ''',''' + P.Text + ''')';
ADOTailles.ExecSQL
```

The numeric field is prixVente;

I used this but still the same error:

```
ADOTailles.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO tailles (numOF, taille, quantite, prixVente) VALUES(''' + numOF.Text + ''',''' + C.Caption + ''',''' + Q.Text + ''',CAST(''' + P.Text + ''' AS numeric(5, 2)))');
ADOTailles.ExecSQL
```

NOTE: If I put an INTEGER there is no error

The full code is:

```
var
     I: Int8;
     C: TCheckBox;
     Q, P: TEdit;
for I := 1 to 16 do Begin
                C := FindComponent('T' + IntToStr(I)) as TCheckBox;
                Q := FindComponent('Q' + IntToStr(I)) as TEdit;
                P := FindComponent('P' + IntToStr(I)) as TEdit;
                if C.Checked = True then begin
                     ADOTailles.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO tailles (numOF, taille, quantite, prixVente) VALUES(''' + numOF.Text + ''',''' + C.Caption + ''',''' + Q.Text + ''',''' + P.Text + ''')';
                     ADOTailles.ExecSQL
                end;
           End;
```

there is no SQL injection because I use this code:

```
StringReplace(aricleFilter.Text, '''', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: You should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - that's very error prone and at risk of **SQL injection**. Instead - use **parametrized queries!** Using parameters also often makes it a lot easier to provide values of different types (like string, int etc.)

Comment: SQL Injection == very un-Pro.

Comment: [Read here about how to use parameters with ADOQuery in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa050101a.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a SQL query by appending text; use parameters.

Or you'll fall into the [Bobby Tables SQL injection trap](http://xkcd.com/327/).

It makes it way easier to get rid of these errors too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your string contains not numeric symbols or incorrect decimal separator (for example "," instead of ".").

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the value for the price between quotes

```
... ''',''' + P.Text + ''')';
```

This is what causes SQLServer to try a conversion from varchar to a number. To prevent that, you will have to leave of the quotes:

```
... ''',' + P.Text + ')';
```

and make sure that P.Text contains the decimal and thousands separators that SQL Server expects. Preferably only the decimal separator. You can always do the conversion yourself using StrToFloat or StrToFloatDef with P.Text as the input and then reformat that for SQLServer.

From what I can remember, SQL Server expects the US separators in SQL statements, which means you need to use a point as the decimal separator.

Comment: I use the Frensh system separators ","

Comment: As I know, SQL Server use the separator used by the system.